# Ich gehe in ein Restaurant essen / zum Essen

Tags: preposition

> Ich gehe in ein Restaurant essen.
>
> Ich gehe in ein Restaurant zum Essen.

Do both sentences work? What is the difference besides here *Essen* is a noun and not a verb?

Comment: Both sound a bit clumsy, IMO. I would say: *Ich gehe essen*. The restaurant would be implied. If it were **not** in a restaurant, I would mention that.

Comment: For me as an Austrian native speaker, using then noun in **zum Essen** implies that you are talking about a recurring meal time (say *Mittagessen*). Normally, you would have the meal at home, but today, you'll have it at a restaurant.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences mean the same thing.

At first I thought that *Ich gehe in ein Restaurant zum Essen* puts emphasis on the fact that you're going there to eat (and not to have a drink) and that *Ich gehe in ein Restaurant essen* puts emphasis on the fact that you're going to eat at a restaurant.

However, it occurred to me that both sentences can be pronounced so that the mean both.

> Ich gehe in ein **Restaurant** essen (emphasis on the restaurant)
>   Ich gehe in ein Restaurant **essen** (emphasis on eating there)
>   Ich gehe in ein **Restaurant** zum Essen
>   Ich gehe in ein Restaurant zum **Essen**

The sentence *Ich gehe in ein **Restaurant** zum Essen* could (and this would be a very rare interpretation) also mean something like *If I do eat at all, I will do so at a restaurant and nowhere else*.